# excel vba chart .top and cell .top position not consistent

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am generating multiple charts using excel vba.  I have been placing the table data on the worksheet and generating the chart over top to hide the table.  Works except as you get further down the sheet using a cell address .TOP and setting chart .TOP to the same value doesn't produce the same result.

For the first chart

When I examine for active cell B3 .top = 28.8

When I examine for selected chart test1 and look at activechart.parent.top = 28.9500007629394

[picture showing cells(3,2).Top, and activechart.top circled in red  the chart table is in cells(7,4) obscured by chart as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5CnU.png)

If you scrolldown 20 charts...
[picture showing 20th iteration of chart not hiding the table using the same generated .Top as above  ][[2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg3lH.png)

When I examine for active cell B573 .top = 8236.8

When I examine for selected chart test20 and look at activechart.parent.top = 8236.7998046875

Using the marker X in cell b573 should be covered, but the top of the chart is visually at b579,appearing 6 rows lower and exposing all of the table  information.

I've seen mention of zoom causing problems and I am at zoom = 100%

I may be able to fudge this, but I'm not sure that it work everywhere.

I'm open to ideas.

Using two routines to peek at ActiveChart.Parent.top and activecell.top

```
Sub Button4_Click() 'select the chart you want to see .TOP in Q1
Sheet1.Range("Q1").Value = ActiveChart.Parent.Top
End Sub

Sub Button5_Click() 'select the cell you want to see .TOP in T1
Sheet1.Range("T1").Value = ActiveCell.Top
End Sub

Sub PlotDrift()

Dim origin As Range
Dim rngToChart As Range

Dim iLoop As Integer

For iLoop = 0 To 20 

  Set origin = Sheet1.Range("d" & iLoop * 30 + 7)

  origin.Offset(0, 1) = "red"

  origin.Offset(0, 2) = "blue"

  origin.Offset(1, 0) = "test" & (1 + iLoop)

        
  origin.Offset(1, 1) = "62.0%"

  origin.Offset(1, 2) = "38.0%"

    
  origin.Offset(-4, -2).Value = "X" ' top left cell that should be covered.
    
   
  Set rngToChart = Sheet1.Range(origin.Offset(0, 0), origin.Offset(1, 2))
 
  rngToChart.Select
     
  Dim ChartRange As Range
     
  Set ChartRange = rngToChart.Offset(-4, -2).Resize(RowSize:=18, ColumnSize:=9)

    ttop = ChartRange.Top
    TLeft = ChartRange.Left
    TWidth = ChartRange.Width
    THeight = ChartRange.Height
 
   ' rngtochart... is selected so just add chart to plot it.
 
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered, TLeft, ttop, TWidth, THeight).Select
   
   ' document in column 1 what excel says it is doing.

   origin.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-1, -3).Value = ChartRange.Top

   origin.Cells(1, 1).Offset(-2, -3).Value = ActiveChart.Parent.Top

Next iLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: I can add a chart drift weighting for top and that is working now, but I'm somewhat convinced that it will come back to bite me.   
'fudging it
Dim chartDriftWeighting as double
' arrived at by looking at the amount of drift ~6060 rows down and the expected (rough guess)
chartDriftWeighting = 0.989579898
ttop = ChartRange.Top * chartDriftWeighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misalignment is specific to my non-main monitor and was caused by the Windows setting *Fix Scaling for Apps*.

I had asked a similar stackoverflow question about generated checkbox alignment [vba  generated checkboxes not aligning with cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843596/excel-vba-generated-checkboxes-not-aligning-with-cells) and found that the problem disappeared in my spreadsheet example.  I recently revisited the issue and found the problem had reappeared in the saved spreadsheet.

I restarted the computer and opened the saved spreadsheet on the main monitor instead of the extended monitor and the problem went away.

So I looked at monitor settings and noticed one labeled *Advanced monitor settings*, and under that *Fix Scaling for Apps*.  *Fix Scaling for Apps* notes that it only works for the main monitor.  I have turned it off, and the .left and .top are now consistent between both monitors.