# Excel VBA generated checkboxes not aligning with cells

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I would like to create a column of 100 checkboxes to select rows.
I can create the checkboxes but as they go further down the sheet the checkboxes slowly diverge from the desired rows.
Checkbox labeled for row 101 - chkbox101 ends up in row 102.  [checkbox labeled chkbox101 in row 102](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYM8C.png)

```
Dim cBox As CheckBox

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("a2:a101")
  Set cBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top , cell.Width, cell.Height)
     
  cBox.Text = "CHKBX " & cell.Row
                
       
Next cell
```

My zoom setting is 100%
My Row height is 14.4

I've made a standalone spreadsheet, completely blank with just this macro in it.

I have had this happen before in another spreadsheet, basically the same coding technique.

And of course, now I am unable to get it to occur for me either.  I will see if I can chase the cause in another way.  I will update if/when I find my cause/error.

Comment: I cant get this to happen for mine.  Can you show where it first happens?

Comment: I can confirm, nothing wrong happens with the above code. I places the check boxes exactly where they should be. I cannot reproduce the problem you describe. Can you share your workbook?

Comment: What is the row height? I've tried for 18 and 20 pixels. Both work correctly.

Comment: What's your worksheet Zoom setting?

Comment: Hard to believe but in 2023 with Office365 this can still happen and no solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by running the spreadsheet on the extended desktop monitor and having fix scaling for apps turned on.

I am using a laptop with the display extended over to a second monitor.  The when the spreadsheet is completely on the  laptop monitor,  the code achieves the expected results (Column A) (why I couldn't get it to happen above).  When the code is run with the spreadsheet even partially on the external monitor the issue of non alignment shows up (Column C) - the checkboxes do not stay in the appropriate rows.

Which monitor the code is run on changes the output when fix scaling for apps is turned on.

I also changed the macro a little to allow changing the output column.

```
Sub InsertCheckboxes()
```

Dim cBox As CheckBox

Dim ThisCol As String
ThisCol = Sheet1.Range("d1").Value

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range(ThisCol & "2:" & ThisCol & "101")
Set cBox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)

cBox.Text = "CHKBX " & cell.Row

Next cell
End Sub

and attached here is a screen shot of what that looks like
[picture of original checkbox alignment issues and with fix scaling turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4XT5.png)

col a checkboxes with fix scaling **on**, and the spreadsheet on the main display
Checkbox labeled for row 101 - chkbox101 ends up in row 101 as expected

col C checkboxes with fix scaling **on**, and the spreadsheet on the other display
Checkbox labeled for row 101 - chkbox101 ends up in row 102

col e checkboxes with fix scaling **OFF**, and the spreadsheet on the other display
Checkbox labeled for row 101 - chkbox101 ends up in row 101 as expected