# Excel VBA Aligning charts to cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large spreadsheet with a lot of charts on it.
I also have a reference sheet with the names of the charts, and which row they should be aligned to.

[image]

In the first column is the name of the chart, and second column is the Tab and cell location the chart should be aligned to.

This is all so that client can control where the charts go without having to drag and drop them all over the place as there are hundreds of them.

The problem I am having is my code isn't aligning charts to the top of the cell: it's slightly off and the further down the sheet I get (i.e. higher row number) the bigger the offset becomes.

This is a snippet of my code:

shCharts is the sheet that contains the list of charts and their location

```
For rowCtr = 2 To GetLastRow(shCharts)
If shCharts.Cells(rowCtr, colCtr) <> "" Then
    chartName = shCharts.Cells(rowCtr, colCtr)
    worksheetName = Split(shCharts.Cells(rowCtr, colCtr + 1), "!")(0)
    cellAddress = Split(shCharts.Cells(rowCtr, colCtr + 1), "!")(1)
    
    With masterWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetName)
        .Activate
        .Shapes(chartName).Top = .Range(cellAddress).Top
        .Shapes(chartName).Left = .Range(cellAddress).Left
    End With
End If
Next rowCtr
```

Lining up left is perfect, however lining up the top is slightly off, and increases further down the rows.
e.g.:

[image]

This graph is meant to be lined up to cell F166, but the offset has gotten so bad, it is inside row 167 instead.

I'm not sure where this misalignment is coming from.

Comment: Might be relevant [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67744814/11318818)?

Comment: thanks for that... seems to have helped. How annoying. I thought it was because of my code

Answer (score 0):

Cutting and pasting the chart into the desired cell should fix misalignments, I use something similar for pngs myself. Try:

```vb
    For rowCtr = 2 To GetLastRow(shCharts)
    If shCharts.Cells(rowCtr, colCtr) <> "" Then
        chartName = shCharts.Cells(rowCtr, colCtr)
        worksheetName = Split(shCharts.Cells(rowCtr, colCtr + 1), "!")(0)
        cellAddress = Split(shCharts.Cells(rowCtr, colCtr + 1), "!")(1)
        
        With masterWorkbook.Worksheets(worksheetName)
            .Activate
            .Shapes(chartName).Cut
            .Range(cellAddress).Select
            .Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clear clipboard
        End With
    End If
    Next rowCtr
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't want the charts within the cell, since it will resize and mess up the rest of the spreadsheet

Comment: they will not be "within" the cell, but rather move the top left corner of the chart to the top left corner of the specified cell, just like your code but should work for different scalings